# Nullpointer asynctask return

Tags: android, csv, android-asynctask

I am trying to access a file on a server using `asynctask`, this is my code:

```
new PostTask().execute("http://antoniofalcone.it/fantavoti/gazz.csv");
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
   String url=params[0];

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.d("clientprotocol", log2);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("IOexception: ", log2);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()
                        )
                );
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d("Illegalstate: ", log2);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("IOException2 ", log2);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   return "All Done!";
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
   super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   super.onPostExecute(result);
}
}
```

I have to read that csv file, but i get a `Nullpointerexception` on the `BufferedReader ("reader")`. Working on a local file in assets directory it's fine. 
Can anyone help me?

Here is the full logcat:

```
08-31 18:16:54.930: W/dalvikvm(2218): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4ceeb20)
08-31 18:16:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-31 18:16:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): Process: com.falc1.fantacalcio2, PID: 2218
08-31 18:16:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.falc1.fantacalcio2/com.falc1.fantacalcio2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-31 18:16:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
08-31 18:16:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-31 18:16:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-31 18:16:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2218):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-31 18:16:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2218):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-31 18:16:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2218):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-31 18:16:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-31 18:16:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2218):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-31 18:16:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2218):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-31 18:16:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2218):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-31 18:16:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2218):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-31 18:16:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2218):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-31 18:16:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-31 18:16:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2218):     at fragments.VotiFragment.readCsv(VotiFragment.java:178)
08-31 18:16:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2218):     at fragments.VotiFragment.onCreateView(VotiFragment.java:75)
08-31 18:16:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2218):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
08-31 18:16:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2218):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
08-31 18:16:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2218):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
08-31 18:16:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2218):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
08-31 18:16:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2218):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
08-31 18:16:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2218):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240)
08-31 18:16:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
08-31 18:16:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2218):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Are any of the stacktraces in your catch statements executing?

Comment: Posting now the full log

Comment: @AntonioFalcone : post `readCsv` method code

Answer (score 2):

The statement, `response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);` is properly wrapped by a try/catch block, but if an exception is thrown (such as the case when the server is unreachable, incorrect URL, or the network is down), then the catch blocks just print the exception and **continues on**.  That means the subsequent statement:

`reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()
                        )`

Will hit a null pointer exception because `response` is null.  Your catch blocks for the httpClient.execute statement should just `return` after printing out the error exception.  A better approach would be have just one set of try catch blocks for both the request and response parsing. Something like the following:

```
HttpResponse response = null;
try {
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
} catch (IOException ioex) {
    Log.d(TAG, "IOException", ioex);
} catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
    Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException", ise);
}
```

Since the log statements can print an exception with a message, I've just combined that for you. You don't need the reduntant printStateTrace statements.  Since ClientProtocolException inherits from IOException, you just need to catch the base class.

And for bonus, you can make your log statements more filterable by declaring a "TAG" variable in your class as follows:

```
public static final String TAG = VotiFragment.class.getSimpleName();
```

And now that I'm done cleaning up your code, I just realized another issue you have.  The whole point of your asynctask is to avoid doing network I/O on the main thread.  But all your asynctask does is starts the HTTP request, but doesn't actually parse the response.  It just creates the reader object which I presume you actually stream from on your UI thread. That means the remaining network i/o on the main thread unless the response was fully buffered.  I would advise that you do all the parsing in the background task.

Comment: @AntonioFalcone - most likely because your real crash is on line 178 of VotiFragment.java.  `at fragments.VotiFragment.readCsv(VotiFragment.java:178)`

Comment: Your `reader` variable in readCsv is probably null. What have you done to debug that?

Answer (score 0):

This is `readCsv` code:

public void readCsv() throws IOException{

```
     String line = "";
     db.beginTransaction();
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] colums = line.split(",");
                    if (colums.length > 23) {
                        Log.d("CSVParser", "Skipping Bad CSV Row");
                        continue;
                    }

                    Player play1 = new Player(colums[1].trim(), colums[2].trim(), Integer.parseInt(colums[3]), 
                            Integer.parseInt(colums[4]), Integer.parseInt(colums[5]),
                            Double.parseDouble(colums[6]), Double.parseDouble(colums[7]), Integer.parseInt(colums[8]), 
                            Double.parseDouble(colums[9]), Integer.parseInt(colums[10]), 
                            Integer.parseInt(colums[11]), Integer.parseInt(colums[12]));

                    db.addPlayer(play1);

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       db.setTransactionSuccessful();
       db.beginTransaction();

    }
```