# Android NullPointerException lock == null

Tags: java, android, csv, nullpointerexception

i'm trying to parse a csv file on a server using `AsyncTask`. This is my code:

```
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            InputStream inStream = null;


            URL stockURL = null;
            try {
                stockURL = new URL("http://antoniofalcone.it/fantavoti/gazz.csv");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            BufferedReader input = null;
            try {
                input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stockURL.openStream()));
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }           
            String line = "";

                    try {
                        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                        String[] colums = line.split(",");
                            if (colums.length > 13) {
                                Log.d("CSVParser", "Skipping Bad CSV Row");
                                continue;
                            }

                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



   return "All Done!";
}
```

I get a NullPointerException: lock == null . How can i fix that? This is the full logcat:

```
08-31 21:42:28.918: E/OpenGLRenderer(2774): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
08-31 21:42:28.918: E/AndroidRuntime(2774): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-31 21:42:28.918: E/AndroidRuntime(2774): Process: com.example.task, PID: 2774
08-31 21:42:28.918: E/AndroidRuntime(2774): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-31 21:42:28.918: E/AndroidRuntime(2774):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
08-31 21:42:28.918: E/AndroidRuntime(2774):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
08-31 21:42:28.918: E/AndroidRuntime(2774):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
08-31 21:42:28.918: E/AndroidRuntime(2774):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
08-31 21:42:28.918: E/AndroidRuntime(2774):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
08-31 21:42:28.918: E/AndroidRuntime(2774):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-31 21:42:28.918: E/AndroidRuntime(2774):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-31 21:42:28.918: E/AndroidRuntime(2774):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-31 21:42:28.918: E/AndroidRuntime(2774): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
08-31 21:42:28.918: E/AndroidRuntime(2774):     at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:64)
08-31 21:42:28.918: E/AndroidRuntime(2774):     at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:122)
08-31 21:42:28.918: E/AndroidRuntime(2774):     at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:59)
08-31 21:42:28.918: E/AndroidRuntime(2774):     at com.example.task.MainActivity$PostTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:85)
08-31 21:42:28.918: E/AndroidRuntime(2774):     at com.example.task.MainActivity$PostTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
08-31 21:42:28.918: E/AndroidRuntime(2774):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
08-31 21:42:28.918: E/AndroidRuntime(2774):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-31 21:42:28.918: E/AndroidRuntime(2774):     ... 4 more
08-31 21:42:28.922: E/OpenGLRenderer(2774): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
08-31 21:42:28.926: E/OpenGLRenderer(2774): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
08-31 21:42:28.934: E/OpenGLRenderer(2774): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
```

Comment: It's not that you've already asked a [near identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594817/nullpointer-asynctask-return) once today on another post that bothers me. It's the fact that the code you are posting will still has the **SAME BUGS** as pointed out by answers in your previous question.  Your code continues to swallow exceptions with a try/catch block and then **CONTINUES ON** without returning - as if there never was an error. And you wonder why your program is crashing!

Comment: And so what? What can i do to fix my code? @selbie

Answer (score 0):

As I've pointed out to you in other answers and comments - catching an exceptions and then continuing is absolutely wrong and is the most likely reason for your crash.

With that being said, this is a better way to open a URL stream and parse the contents.

And while we are at it, let's separate the downloading of the content separate from the parsing of the content. That makes it easier to debug and easier to test.  To do that, let's define a little helper function, [one I've used in my own code](https://github.com/jselbie/wrekonline/blob/master/src/com/selbie/wrek/ContentDownloader.java), to download a file into a String over http.

```
public class ContentDownloader
{
    public static String downloadString(String urlstring) throws IOException
    {
        URL url = new URL(urlstring);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        connection.setReadTimeout(30000);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(30000);

        connection.connect();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        char [] buffer = new char[5000];

        while (true)
        {
            int result = reader.read(buffer);
            if (result < 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            sb.append(buffer, 0, result);
        }

        String response = sb.toString();
        return response;
    }
}
```

Now let's define a little parse helper that can convert the downloaded string into multiple lines and splits up each CSV line into columns. You can modify this as needed

```
public class CSVParser
{
    public static ArrayList<String[]> parse(String str)
    {
        ArrayList<String[]> parsed_lines = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        String lines [] = str.split("\\r?\\n");
        for (String row : lines)
        {
            row = row.trim();
            if (row.length == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            String [] columns = row.split(",");
            for (int x = 0; x < columns.length; x++)
            {
                columns[x] = columns[x].trim();
            }
            parsed_lines.add(columns);
        }
        return parsed_lines;
    }
}
```

And so now, your asynctask is just simply this:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String content = null;
    ArrayList<String[]> parsed_lines = null;

    try {
        content = ContentDownloader.downloadString();
        parsed_lines = CSVParser.parse(content);
    }
    catch(IOException ioex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IOException", ioex);
        return;  // DO NOT CONTINUE IF WE FAILED TO DOWNLOAD
    }

    // if we get to this point here, parsed_lines
    // will be a parsed CSV file
}
```

You are welcome.